# In TestComplete how to get which object the Object Checkpoint was called from during OnLogCheckPoint Event?

Tags: testcomplete

I am currently working on detecting the test information automatically during the test run in test complete.

So my requirement is this.

1. I have a test created in testcomplete
2. I attach the OnLogCheckpoint event having my own code.
3. There I can get checkpoint properties for object checkpoints (they are available in the LogParams)
4. Yet I could not find a way to get on which object the object checkpoint was called.

Is there any way to get this object/alias on which the object checkpoint is executed from the script from the OnLogCheckpoint event or some other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **OnLogCheckpoint** event is fired when a checkpoint message is posted to the log and now when a checkpoint is executed. There is an important difference: in the first case, the target of the event is a log message and not the actual object from the object tree.

However, in a general case such messages contain the object name you need. So, you can parse the log message to get the name of the object. Here is a sample script (JScript) that does this for a Property checkpoint message. I did not test it with other checkpoint types, but it is possible that this code will work with them without any changes or with minimal changes.

```
function GeneralEvents_OnLogCheckpoint(Sender, LogParams)
{
  Log.Message("Object name: " + getObjectNameFromCheckpointMessage(LogParams.StrEx));
}

function getObjectNameFromCheckpointMessage(str)
{
  var re = /<th class='BoldLineTop HB'>Object name:<\/th>\s+<th class='BoldLineTop'>((\w|\(|\)|\.|\s|,|-|")+)<\/th>/;
  var m = re.exec(str);
  if (m === null)
    return "";

  return m[1];
}
```

Update:

The following sample script shows how to get the name of an object validated with an Object checkpoint. The name obtained is a short name, it seems that there is no way to get the full name.

```
function GeneralEvents_OnLogCheckpoint(Sender, LogParams)
{
  Log.Message("Object name: " + getObjectNameFromObjectCheckpointMessage(LogParams.StrEx));
}

function getObjectNameFromObjectCheckpointMessage(str)
{
  var re = /Click here to show or modify data of the checkpoint \"(\w+)\"\./;
  var m = re.exec(str);
  if (m === null)
    return "";

  return Objects.StoredObject(m[1]).Name;
}
```

Comment: Hi Dmitry - thank you for the answer, yet I already did that for the property checkpoints - it has all the information as you mentioned. The issue is it seems there is no feasible way to do the same for the object checkpoints - Alias  or the full path for the object is not available in the LogParams (btw the I did not check the .StrEx parameter since it was not available in the debugger (using TC9) - let me check again and I will write back)

Comment: StrEx property contains the value that is posted to the additional info pane of a log record. I think that it should contain the value you need.

Comment: Unfortunately not - the property is there - yet it contains this value 

`<html><body><a href="projectnode://{GUID}">Click here to show or modify checkpoint "Page_Login". </a></body></html>`

Here GUID cannot be found anywhere else, and the Page_Login is the actual checkpoint itself and not the alias on which the checkpoint itself is applied to.

Comment: It is possible to get the short name in case of the Object Checkpoint. See the update in my answer.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, I was not able to find a way to do it either - the value returned by the updated code does not return correct results (at least did not in my case - it was showing a different page where the same checkpoint was used). Still I could not find either and yours is an improvement. There might be no way of doing this as you mentioned. I will wait a little more while for other possible answers. If there aren't any answers I will mark your answer as correct since there is no known way of finding the correct object solely from the logs.